# Argo Events: Use data filter in sensor to identify modified/added/removed path in mono-repo

Tags: go, argocd, argo-events

I'm using Argo Events and Argo Workflow for my CI/CD chain, which works pretty neat. But I'm having some troubles setting up the **data filter** for the **GitHub webhook payloads** of my mono repo.

I'm trying to let the sensor only trigger the defined workflow if files were changed in a certain subpath. The payload contains three fields **added**, **removed**, **modified**. There the files are listed which were changed in this commit ([webhook-events-and-payloads#push](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push)).

The paths I'm searching for is `service/jobs/*` and `service/common*/*`.

The filter I defined is:

```
          - path: "[commits.#.modified.#(%\"*service*\")#,commits.#.added.#(%\"*service*\")#,commits.#.removed.#(%\"*service*\")#]"
            type: string
            value:
              - "(\bservice/jobs\b)|(\bservice/common*)"
```

I valididated my filter in a tiny **Go** script, as **gjson** is used by Argo Events to apply the data filter.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
    "regexp"
)

const json = `{
    "commits": [
      {
        "added": [
  
        ],
        "removed": [
  
        ],
        "modified": [
          "service/job-manager/README.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "added": [
  
        ],
        "removed": [
            "service/joby/something.md"
        ],
        "modified": [
          "service/job-manager/something.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "added": [
  
        ],
        "removed": [
            "service/joby/something.md"
        ],
        "modified": [
          "service/joby/someother.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "head_commit": {
      "added": [
        "service/job-manager/something.md"
      ],
      "removed": [
        "service/joby/something.md"
      ],
      "modified": [
        "service/job-manager/README.md"
      ]
    }
  }`

func main() {
    value := gjson.Get(json, "[commits.#.modified.#(%\"*service*\")#,commits.#.added.#(%\"*service*\")#,commits.#.removed.#(%\"*service*\")#]")
    println(value.String())

    matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(`(\bservice/job-manager\b)|(\bservice/common*)`, value.String())
    println(matched) // string is contained?
}
```

The script gives me the results I expect. But for the same webhook payload the workflow is not triggered, when adding the data filter to the sensor.

Someone any ideas?

---

**UPDATED:**

Thanks for the hint incl. `body.` in the paths.

I ended up setting the filters:

```
- path: "[body.commits.#.modified.#()#,body.commits.#.added.#()#,body.commits.#.removed.#()#]"
  type: string
  value:
    - ".*service/jobs.*"
    - ".*service/common.*"
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Path shoud start with `body.`
- Value should add escape special character with `\\`

So the data filter should be

```
- path: "[body.commits.#.modified.#(%\"*service*\")#,body.commits.#.added.#(%\"*service*\")#,body.commits.#.removed.#(%\"*service*\")#]"
  type: string
  value:
    - "(\\bservice/jobs\\b)|(\\bservice/common*)"
```